# python get most common words , greater tha 3 characters

Tags: python, count

Hi I m quite new of Python
I m trying to figured out how to get the most common words listed in clean.txt file , but only word lenght > 3

`

```
import re

from collections import Counter

words  = re.findall(r'\w+', open('clean.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().lower())
count = Counter(words).most_common(100)

# define a sort key
def sort_key(count):
    return count[1]

def read_data():
    f = open('clean.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    s = f.read()
    x = s.split()
    for i in x:
        if len(i) > 5:
            print(i)

count.sort(key=sort_key, reverse=True)

print (count)
```

`

I tried print read_data but I ve got listed all words without showing number of times mentioned

Comment: I'm not sure if you want: from the top 100 words, keep only the words that have more than 3 characters OR the top 100 words that have more than 3 characters. Your title suggests the former, but your code suggests the latter

Comment: If you use this regex `\w{3,}` you can filter all the words that have 3 or more characters.